# What is the purpose of the intake manifold cover on a Honda S2000?

Tags: honda, s2000

On a 2001 Honda S2000 (or any other car for that matter) does the intake manifold cover (plastic piece held on with two 10mm acorn nuts) actually protect against something, or is it purely aesthetic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intake manifold cover is purely cosmetic and can be removed without causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you refer to, if you are talking about the cover on the airbox, where the air filter sits, it is to stop your engine from sucking in sludge and dust.